# Geocortex Essentials 4.7 Issues with HTTP ArcGIS Services

Tags: arcgis-server, geocortex

Just upgraded to **Geocortex Essentials 4.7** and am having some issues getting ArcGIS Services into it from an ArcGIS Server using **http** as oppose to https.

It allows me to connect and add the service, but in the view nothing will come up. I can't seem to get a good answer from Geocortex (I don't think they know) and I can't find the Admin or User Guide for 4.7.

- I do know that **http** and **https** services are not allowed in the same Geocortex web app, but all I am adding are http services.
- Https services work fine, no problems
- Geocortex Essentials is https.

Comment: How are you trying to get answers from us?  I looked in our support queue and community forum and couldn't see anything about http-only issues (although the search terms are quite vague)

Comment: Just hoping someone is having a similar issue. Our old geocortex 3x worked fine pulling in HTTP services. but this version is having a lot of issues with HTTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a service to an Essentials Site, the Essentials Manager application will try to make a web request to that service to get the service info. This connection is made from the server to the map, not your browser.

If there's anything in the network stack from the server to the Internet that could interfere with a web request, then you can see issues like this.

We've seen firewalls that try to upgrade HTTP to HTTPS traffic (by replacing content) and that causes lots of very strange things to happen.

An easy test is to see if you can add any of the services on http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services.

Answer (score 3):

There is some TIFF.js file missing in the build. It is required to render the map preview in your Essentials Manager.   Press F12 in your Chrome browser and it will highlight in red what libraries cannot be found .

Get it from:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Esri/arcgis-js-api/master/layers/rasterFormats/TiffDecoder.js

Copy to:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Latitude Geographics\Geocortex Essentials\GXE470\REST Elements\Manager\Content\EmbeddedViewer\Resources\Scripts\esri\layers\rasterFormats

Comment: The missing TiffDecoder.js only affects sites with ImageServer services, and was fixed with the Essentials 4.7.1 release.  It shouldn't be related to issues with HTTP vs. HTTPS.